# How can i Add authentication for JSONAPI

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-identity, microservices, json-api

I want to add authentication for a JSON API. Our project has a relationship with multiple tables, for example:

There are two entities

1. `student`
2. `teacher`

the `student` entity has a many-to-many relationship with the `teacher` entity
and vice-versa.

A student only can view student details, but in this case we use `=>`

```
student?include=teacher
```

can get the teachers details also how to prevent include function with
role-based from JWT token

Comment: can you show your sample code what you have tried?

Comment: [JSON:API specification](https://jsonapi.org/) does not cover authentification. It's up to your implementation how to handle that one.

Comment: I just add Authentication on the controller but it didn't affect on include function